# Disable UINavigationBar Animation when StatusBar is hidden/shown

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

When the status bar is hidden or shown on a navigation controller in iOS 7, the navigationBar will move up or down. How can I get it so that the navigationBar height = it's height + the status bar offset at all times?

Tinder is a good example of an app that successfully does this when transitioning to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you found the solution. i am still searching for a better one but you can set the the origin of the navigation bar when the animation starts

[How to fade out the status bar while not hiding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941774/how-to-fade-out-the-status-bar-while-not-hiding-it/21082725#21082725)

but if you have set the navigationBar.translucent = NO and if you have child viewcontrollers the view controllers will also move. so you will have to work with it too.

Comment: I ended up just not using the navigation controller's navbar and making my own and making it the height of the status bar (20 points) + the standard height of a UINavigationBar. That way when the status bar hides, the nav bar just stays at the same height since it's not being managed by the UINavigationController