# How can I hide the status bar without affecting child view layout in a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Here's a GIF of the layout bug I'm trying to fix:

[image: Bad autolayout]

If you watch closely, you can see the top view shifting up by 20 points at the beginning of the transition. It might not be very noticeable, but now I can't stop seeing it and I would really like to fix it.

I think it's happening because the status bar is being hidden, but it only happens when I'm using a UIPageViewController. It doesn't happen for any views that are added normally.

Is there any way I can fix the constraints that this page view controller is installing on it's child views? I think it might be getting confused with `topLayoutGuide` somewhere, but I couldn't find a way to fix it.

Comment: what do you want? is the status bar purposely in there?

Comment: Yes the status bar is in the first view on purpose, and I'm also hiding it on purpose. I want to be able to hide the status bar without affecting the frame of the view controller inside the UIPageViewController.

Comment: and you're hiding it because you don't want it showing when your modal view pops out? is that right?

Comment: Yep, the modal view is overriding `prefersStatusBarHidden` and returning `false`, which hides the status bar.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with it too.

Comment: @JoeWaller I haven't looked at this for a while, but check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21006408/304706

That's how you can fade out the status bar without affecting layout.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hide the status bar on your 1st page since you placed it on purpose. Just disable the status bar on the modal view you're popping out.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm doing, and this is causing the layout bug.

Comment: you need to implement the completion handler that will do the hiding of the status bar only after the presentation of the modal view.